# How to remove Plymouth Boot Animation manager and keep the default boot screen

Tags: 11.10, boot, plymouth

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit. Recently, I installed the Plymouth boot screen to change the boot animation. Now I would like to remove it. I want to revert to the default animation it was before I installed Plymouth. However, I cannot remove Plymouth without removing several other critical packages. Does anyone know how I can remove Plymouth and revert to my original boot animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not remove "plymouth" as you say carries packages with it that are vital.
Go to synaptic type plymouth in search window and go to "plymouth themes"
choose the theme you want looks like text and install it. (Make sure it is a Plymouth Theme)
Now run below in a terminal and pick out theme you wish to use by the number.
Code:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Once you have chosen and installed now run below:
Code:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Code:

```
sudo reboot
```