# Plymouth did not install properly

Tags: plymouth, re-installation

I was installing the plymouth manager in hopes of making a custom loading screen.  While the terminal was working, my computer unexpectedly powered off.  I can open up the manager and it appears to do what it is supposed to (minus the fact that I can't make my own theme) and the screen only shows on powering down.  Anyway, all of the advice I have seen so far have resulted in errors and nothing getting fixed.  I do not have permissions to simply select the folder and delete it for some reason and I have not been able to find out how to grant myself those permissions.

I guess my question then is how do I get rid of the plymouth manager so I can reinstall it properly?

Already tried:

-Installation - http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/install-plymouth-manager-and-change.html

-Removal - [How to remove Plymouth Boot Animation manager and keep the default boot screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83253/how-to-remove-plymouth-boot-animation-manager-and-keep-the-default-boot-screen)

-Permissions - [How do I change my user permissions to edit /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85333/how-do-i-change-my-user-permissions-to-edit-etc-apt-sources-list)

-Theming Guide - http://brej.org/blog/?p=158

Comment: Please add to your question more information about the steps that you have taken until attempting to fix this issue. Include guide, other open questions that you might have followed and detailed information on why those did not work for you.

Comment: Added a few though I'm sure there were a few more that I can't find back.  As for why they didn't work, I'm not sure.  If I knew then I could probably fix it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if no one has an answer then I will propose my own solution.  Follow these steps:

1. Take Ubuntu install disk
2. Insert into CD/DVD drive
3. Reinstall OS