# Minimizing Or Closing Apps Cause Ubuntu To Freeze

Tags: unity, gnome, xfce

So I want to try Gnome Environment and XFCE Environment, So I installed Both of them But I Did Disable Unity Plug-ings. But some How I managed to Uninstalled Both Environment and Got back my Unity. But

1. There is Still Gnome Logo loading when ubuntu Boots up.
2. after Sufering In desktop and opening apps it's goes ok but after few minutes when I Minimize or try to close some process suddenly My Ubuntu Freezes Until I Press CTRL+ALT+DEL it gets normal again.

Please Need Smooth Running for my Ubuntu HELP.

Comment: you don't need to disable unity plugin . . . you choose unity, xfce, or gnome-shell from the login screen where you put in your user name and password. You have to click on the ubuntu icon for these options.

Comment: the gnome logo is your "plymouth theme" you can switch plymouth themes or uninstall the gnome theme. do a search with the command `dpkg -l | grep plymouth` to list currently installed plymouth related applications. use `sudo apt-get remove` or `sudo apt-get purge` followed by the app to uninstall to get rid of whatever it is you want to uninstall.

Comment: to change plymouth theme run the following commands from an open terminal: `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` make your selection and then run `sudo update-initramfs -u` the changes will show next boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have the ubuntu desktop fully installed by opening a terminal and executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Now, execute the following commands to reset unity and compiz (remember, unity *is* a compiz plugin; if you disable the plugin, you disable unity):

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
nohup setsid unity
```

Your screen will flash and it might take few moments for things to return to normal. If you want to, you can go ahead and reboot instead.

You should also take a look at these:

[Switching window manager/desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/a/400581/167115)

[How to remove Plymouth Boot Animation manager and keep the default boot screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83253/how-to-remove-plymouth-boot-animation-manager-and-keep-the-default-boot-screen)

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Ubuntu freezes only when it is about to have nothing opened. To fix that I first opened terminal (Control+ALT+T) then opened the software center (don't minimize anything yet!!!) then I got the screenlets app. The I opened screenlets, chose the one I liked and clicked "start/stop" and "start on startup" tickboxes on the bottom left of the screenlets app. Then I close everything and the screenlet was on the desktop. Since the screenlet was opened Ubuntu didn't freeze, since there was a thing opened.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is nautilus crashing as nautilus is responsible for the desktop items. Try out the following solutions if anything works out :

Try removing the nautilus config files

```
rm -rf ~/.nautilus
```

If it doesn't work out , remove nautilus open terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-open-terminal
```

If nothing works, until the fix comes around,  just open nautilus before minimizing the last open window. I hope this helps